# Pstools not working on LAN network

Tags: windows-7, networking, psexec

I am using a 64 bit windows 7 system with LAN connectivity but unable to use pstools ,I don't understand why it is showing the below output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71PZY.png)

i.e. it is showing :
  **coudn't access ip address** and
  **The network path was not found**

Answer (score 0):

So your title is wrong - pstools IS working.
It just can't connect, what might have several reasons:
Is the Service RemoteRegistry on the remote pc running?
Does your account have access to the remote registry?

cite from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psinfo

```
Since PsInfo relies on remote Registry access to obtain its data, 
the remote system must be running the Remote Registry service
and the account from which you run PsInfo must have access to the
HKLM\System portion of the remote Registry.
```